# python tkinter bind <Leave> for 2 widgets in one moment

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, виджет, bind

Если 2-ух виджетов указатель мыши оставил то делать функцию

```
widget1 and widget2.bind("<Leave>", program)
```

Answer (score 2):

`and` так не работает. `and` - это логическая операция. Для аргументов булевого типа (`True` или `False`) возвращает `True` если оба аргумента `True` (или `False`, если один или оба аргумента `False`), для всех остальных объектов если один из объектов "ложный" (0, `False`, `None`, пустой список/tuple/словарь, обобщенно - если метод `__bool__` объекта возвращает `False`) то возвращает его (первый из ложных аргументов, если они оба ложные, например результатом `0 and None` будет 0), иначе возвращает второй объект.

Кроме того, у `and` более низкий приоритет, чем у вызова метода, поэтому сначала произойдет вызов метода `bind` у второго объекта, потом будет выполнена операция `and` между первым объектом и результатом вызова метода `bind`. `bind` ничего не возвращает, для Python это эквивалентно возврату `None`, так что результатом выполнения всей конструкции будет `None`. Но так как результат операции `and` потом никак не учитывается, то вся строка эквивалентна просто `widget2.bind("<Leave>", program)`.

Как выполнить привязку к событию `<Leave>` обоих объектов - просто отдельно сделайте `bind` для первого виджета, потом отдельно для второго.

```
widget1.bind("<Leave>", program)
widget2.bind("<Leave>", program)
```

Если виджетов много, можно делать привязку через цикл (если вы используете нумерованные переменные, то вообще имеет смысл заменить отдельные переменные на список):

```
for w in [widget1, widget2]:
    w.bind("<Leave>", program)
```

Либо, поместить все виджеты в один фрейм, и привязываться к событию `<Leave>` фрейма, а не каждого отдельного виджета.